# Is Charles the pilot of the seagull plane?

Tags: the-pilots-love-song, the-princess-and-the-pilot

In *Toaru Hikuushi e no Koiuta*, ep 8: A seagull-crested aquamarine plane piloted by a ridiculously skilled person helps Kal-el. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsmp7.jpg))

We later learn that Levamme is coming to help them. (I have not seen the last episodes yet).

**Is the pilot of that plane Charles, from *The Princess and Pilot*?**

I think the light novels might shed some light on it, but my Japanese reading skills suck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read the *Koiuta* light novels, but according to [this guy on Chiebukuro](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11120081821) and [the Wikipedia article for *Koiuta*](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E9%A3%9B%E7%A9%BA%E5%A3%AB%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E6%81%8B%E6%AD%8C#.E7.A5.9E.E8.81.96.E3.83.AC.E3.83.B4.E3.82.A1.E3.83.BC.E3.83.A0.E7.9A.87.E5.9B.BD), there are strong indications that the pilot of the seagull plane is, in fact, Charles KARINO from *The Princess and the Pilot*. However, this is never made explicit. There is apparently a scene in the fourth volume where he and Kal-el have a conversation, but despite this, his name is never revealed.

The *Koiuta* light novels are complete (no further volumes are expected to be published), so this is probably as good an answer as you're going to get.

Comment: From the epilogue of the Tsuioku novel, the author would be shooting himself in the foot if he made clear that Charles has appeared later in the cronology. I think it serves two purposes: to make the people that know the first novel wonder and hope (as I did) and to avoid having to flesh out the character to the new audience. I asked the question mostly to confirm this suspicion. But seeing the level of influence Fana has, its hard to believe she wouldn't provide for Charles. Mostly, it was sweet of him to place him like that.